# how to make border-bottom go underneath border-left?

Tags: css, border

i have a xenforo forum running and i was wondering about the border property.

this is the visual look of the Quote block of Xenforo:
[image]

I added a border property and these are the css:

```
.XenBase .messageContent .bbCodeQuote .attribution {
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    border-left: 3px solid #9f0000;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #gray;
    color: #727272;
}

.XenBase .messageContent .bbCodeQuote .quoteContainer {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-left: 3px solid #9f0000;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

What I want to happen is the border-bottom 1px gray to be underneath the border-left 3px red. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to **reproduce** it in the question itself preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need something like this:

```
.XenBase .messageContent .bbCodeQuote  {
    border-left: 3px solid #9f0000;
}

.XenBase .messageContent .bbCodeQuote .attribution {
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #gray;
    color: #727272;
}

.XenBase .messageContent .bbCodeQuote .quoteContainer {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Parent div have red border.

Comment: After applying it, it didn't seem to work, and when I inspected the element, the property was crossed out? http://i.imgur.com/Hu8qy9n.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS pseudo-class.

For example:

```
<div class="box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam dignissimos cupiditate dolorum pariatur, assumenda laudantium et ea tenetur corrupti cum at culpa, amet accusamus ducimus eum deserunt magnam deleniti numquam.
</div>

.box {position: relative; border-left: 2px solid red; padding: 10px;}
.box:after {content: ""; position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: -4px; width: 100%; height: 1px; background-color: gray;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pooria_h/gtgfwvx2/

Comment: I tried tweaking the box:after so that I can move the border and it still overlaps the red border.

Comment: Maybe you didn't position `box:after` absolutly? please check JSFiddle that I wrote, otherwise put your code so I can help you.